# Multiple Sharing Options for same App from Gallery

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gallery, intentfilter

I have observed that some apps allow a user to share an image from the gallery app to multiple different activities within the same application. For example, if I try to share a photo from the gallery app to Instagram, there are multiple different choices that show up.[Gallery Share Options I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kp8m.jpg) I was wondering how I could implement this functionality in my Android studio project. When I try to share an image from my gallery, I want there to be multiple sharing options for my app.

Comment: Is this solving Your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665066/how-to-implement-share-via-option-in-android

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to send photos from my app to another app. In the screenshot I provided, I have the gallery app open, and I'm trying to have multiple sharing options for my app when the user clicks the "Share" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add intent-filter tag to your activity in manifest to receive data from sharing

Update your manifest like this

```
      <activity
        android:name=".test.Image2Activity"
        android:label="Activity 1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".test.Image1Activity"
        android:label="Activity 2"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It has intent filter in both activities that accepts image. So when share an image from gallery it will show like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWU3z.png)

The label of your activity will show while sharing.

Learn more about sharing [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)